Set Chrome Policy as 'Recommended' Instead of 'Mandatory' on Windows
I am trying to debug an issue with Chrome's URLAllowList. When I add a policy via HKCU/SOFTWARE/Policies/Google/Chrome/URLAllowList, the policy shows up in the chrome:policy list as Level: 'Mandatory'. On MacOS, a policy will always be Level: 'Recommended' unless a manager is installed.
For my baseline, I want both of these to be the same, and I would prefer to not install a manager as part of my baseline. How can I set a policy's level on Windows?
